# Is a problem with pyautogui or what im doing wrong?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyautogui

I'm doing a code that resolves sudokus, but I'm trying to do it with web scraping. The thing is that the sudoku resolves in a wrong way but just in the web, the result in the console is right. I mean the numbers that are put on the web are not expected according to the console. Idk if it is a problem with some library.

```
def up_solucion(sudoku):
    for row in sudoku:
        for ele in row:
            pg.press(str(ele))
            pg.press("right")
        pg.press("down")
        pg.press("left", presses=8)

    print("Thats it")
    return
```

```
def resolve_sudoku(sudoku):
    for fila in range(9):
        for columna in range(9):
            if sudoku[fila][columna] == 0:

                for valor in range(1, 10):

                    if es_posible(columna, fila, valor, sudoku):

                        sudoku[fila][columna] = valor
                        resuelto = resolver_sudoku(sudoku)
                        if resuelto:
                            return True
                        sudoku[fila][columna] = 0
                return False
    return True
```

I check all the code but I could not find the problem, sorry for my english.